# Microdata for news item in breadcrumb navigation

Tags: typo3, typoscript, microdata, tx-news

With the following code I build my breadcrumb navigation with the according microdata for a [BreadcrumbList](https://schema.org/BreadcrumbList):

```
lib.breadcrumb = COA
lib.breadcrumb {
  wrap = <ol class="list-inline" role="menubar" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/BreadcrumbList">|</ol>

  10 = HMENU
  10 {
    special = rootline
    special.range = 0|-1

    1 = TMENU
    1 {
      wrap = |

      NO {
        allWrap = <li itemprop="itemListElement" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/ListItem">|</li>
        stdWrap.htmlSpecialChars = 1
        linkWrap = |
        doNotLinkIt = 0 |*||*| 1
        ATagBeforeWrap = 1
        ATagTitle.field = nav_title // title
        ATagParams = role="menuitem" itemprop="item"
        stdWrap.wrap = <span itemprop="name">|</span>

        after.cObject = COA
        after.cObject {
          5 = TEXT
          5.dataWrap = <meta itemprop="position" content="{register:count_MENUOBJ}|" />
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This works perfectliy fine, but I have no idea, how to add the item `<meta itemprop="position" content="{register:count_MENUOBJ}|" />` for a newsrecord:

This is how it looks at the moment:

```
// add news title to breadcrumb if needed
[globalVar = GP:tx_news_pi1|news > 0]
  lib.breadcrumb.10.1.NO.doNotLinkIt = 0

  lib.breadcrumb.20 = COA
  lib.breadcrumb.20 {
    wrap = <li class="article" itemprop="itemListElement" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/ListItem">|</li>
    after.cObject = COA
    after.cObject {
      5 = TEXT
      5.dataWrap = <meta itemprop="position" content="{register:count_MENUOBJ}|" />
    }

    10 = RECORDS
    10 {
      dontCheckPid = 1
      tables = tx_news_domain_model_news
      source.data = GP:tx_news_pi1|news
      source.intval = 1
      conf.tx_news_domain_model_news = TEXT
      conf.tx_news_domain_model_news.field = title
      conf.tx_news_domain_model_news.htmlSpecialChars = 1
      wrap = <span itemprop="name">|</span>
    }
  }
[end]
```

Obviously the `{register:count_MENUOBJ}` is not available for the news item.

How can I get the last value of `{register:count_MENUOBJ}` from the menu object and increase it by one for the news item?

Comment: Just a guess, but maybe you must use the "insertData" property (think its a property, correct me if i'm wrong) https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-typoscript/master/en-us/Functions/Stdwrap.html#insertdata

Comment: @Rustyjim Unfortunately this does not help. The whole `after.cObject` part for the news records does not output anything...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem, my solution is to work with the CUR element:

```
lib.breadcrumb = COA
lib.breadcrumb {
  stdWrap.wrap = <ol class="list list--inline" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/BreadcrumbList">|</ol>
  10 = HMENU
  10{
    special = rootline
    special.range = 0|-1
    includeNotInMenu = 1

    1 = TMENU
    1{
      noBlur = 1
      expAll = 1
   NO = 1
      NO.wrapItemAndSub = <li itemprop="itemListElement" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/ListItem">|</li>
      NO.stdWrap.htmlSpecialChars = 1
      NO.stdWrap.htmlSpecialChars.preserveEntities = 1
      #NO.doNotLinkIt = |*| 0 |*| 1
   NO {
    ATagParams = itemprop="item"
    stdWrap.wrap = <span itemprop="name">|</span>
    after = <meta itemprop="position" content="{register:count_MENUOBJ}" />
    after.insertData = 1
   }

    }
  }
}

[(request.getQueryParams()['tx_news_pi1'])['news'] > 0]
 lib.breadcrumb {
  10 {
   1 {
    CUR < .NO
    CUR {
     doNotLinkIt = 1
     stdWrap2 {
        typolink {
           # Detail page
           ATagParams = itemprop="item"
           parameter.field = uid
           additionalParams.data = GP:tx_news_pi1|news
           # If there is a plugin with mode "Detail", the controller and action parameter might be skipped
           additionalParams.wrap = &tx_news_pi1[controller]=News&tx_news_pi1[action]=detail&tx_news_pi1[news]=|
           useCacheHash = 1
           stdWrap = <span itemprop="name">|</span>
        }
      }
     stdWrap.cObject = RECORDS
     stdWrap.cObject {
      if.isTrue.data = GP:tx_news_pi1|news
      dontCheckPid = 1
      tables = tx_news_domain_model_news
      source.data = GP:tx_news_pi1|news
      source.intval = 1
      conf.tx_news_domain_model_news = TEXT
      conf.tx_news_domain_model_news {
       field = title
      }
     }
    }
   }
  }
 }
[global]
```